# Skip-Gram implementation in tensorflow/models - Subsampling of Frequent Words

Tags: c++, tensorflow, word2vec

I have some experiments in mind related to skipgram model. So I have started to study and modify the optimized implementation in **tensorflow/models** repository in `tutorials/embedding/word2vec_kernels.cc`. Suddenly I came above the part where corpus subsampling is done.
According to Tomáš Mikolov paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4546, eq.5), the word should be **kept** with probability

[image: eq1]

where `t` denotes threshold parameter (according to paper chosen as `10^-5`), and `f(w)` frequency of the word `w`,
but the code in `word2vec_kernels.cc` is following:

```
float keep_prob = (std::sqrt(word_freq / (subsample_ * corpus_size_)) + 1) *
                  (subsample_ * corpus_size_) / word_freq;
```

which can be transformed into previously presented notation as
[image: eq2]

What is the motivation behind this change? Is it just to model 'some kind of relation' to corpus size into this formula? Or is it some transformation of the original formula? Was it chosen empirically?

*Edit*: link to the mentioned file on github
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_kernels.cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I guess that without `corpus_size`, the graph looks somewhat the same as the original formula. Corpus size adds a **relation to the corpus size** to the formula and also "it works with the large numbers", so we can compute discard/keep probability without normalizing word frequency to proper distribution.